# powershell basic for loops

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I'm new to powershell, and I am learning how to use for loops function. 
here is the script:

```
$arys = @( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
for ($i=0; $i -le $arys.Length – 1; $i++)
{Write-Host $arys[$i]}
```

The only thing I don't understand is this part:
`$arys[$i]` -> what is the explanation of this script? I mean I can see `$arys` and `$i` are variables, but why is `$i` needs to be put inside the closing brackets `[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$i` contains the number in the current iteration of the loop. The loop counts from `0` through the length of the array.

To get the *item* from the array, you must ask the array for the item at index `$i`, hence `$arys[$i]`. [Square brackets are the indexing operator for arrays](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847882.aspx).

So for example if the value of `$i` were 3, you would get get `$arys[3]` which the value `4` (because the array is indexed starting at `0`).

This might be more apparent if you use an array of strings instead of numbers like `$arys = @( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' )`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that clear up my confusion! :)